# h:selectManyListbox & t:selectItems value attribute difference

Tags: jsf, tomahawk

I'm looking over some existing code and curious as to what the differnce between the 'h:selectManyListbox' & 't:selectItems' value attribute is?

```
<h:selectManyListbox value="#{MyBean.deSelectedFields}" size="10">
  <t:selectItems id="selectItemsId" value="#{MyBean.allSelectedFields}" var="item" itemValue="#{item.value}" itemLabel="#{item.label}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

The documentation for both components states the same thing:
"The value attribute sets the current value for this component."

http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/tomahawk/09-TagReference/tomahawk-selectManyListbox.html

http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_selectItems.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `h:selectManyListbox value` should be bound to a list/array of **selected** select items. They will set the `selected` attribute on the generated HTML `<option>` elements whose value matches the list/array. The `t/f:selectItems value` should be bound to a list/array of **available** select items. They will represent *all* HTML `<option>` elements.

So, they just represents the value of the component itself. It is not true that the value of `t/f:selectItems` is also immediately the value of `h:selectManyListbox`.